# Stale Hibernate createSQLQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a project that is reading from a shared mysql database. There is a large account object that comes from the session (too large, but that is another story).

Problem is that this object has a blance field that is debited by a different process on the same machine. So the user sees the balance of say £20 but in reality their balance is probably a lot lower. There is no way for the app to know when this value changes.

So I thought what i would do is check mysql every time I am asked for the value from the database, but it is through faces, so it asks many times when it asks, so I put in a check so that if it hasn't asked for a few seconds, to do a createSQLquery on just the balance to see if it is different, and if it is, reload the object.

so I do something along the line of:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT Balance from Account").list();
```

and get the value. Some of the time it shows the right balance, but often it shows the previously read balance, where the mysql command line client shows the real value.

Is there a way of clearing this value, or another way of updating the object? I would like ultimately to remove hibernate as it causes me a lot more problems that it solves, but for the moment, I just need the balance to show a value based on the database.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reload that object in your hibernate session. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html

```
sess.refresh(yourReadObject);
```

Maybe clearing the session

```
sess.clear();
```

could help as well. However it probably has more side effects.

Comment: That is what it is supposed to be doing, and I guess, the right thing. I do this when I have determined the object has changed, but it doesn't pick up the changes all the time

Answer (score 1):

Since you are anyway planning to ditch hibernate you can directly use a JDBC connection to bypass the hibernate session without affecting anything else.

```
Connection con = getSession().connection();
PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement("...");
s.setString(1, "...");
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();
```

Comment: That is a good idea, and I didn't know I could do that (although .connection appears to be deprecated). However, it still comes up with the cached results. I got a raw JDBC connection and compared the results (ie, just changing the first line). It came up with different results than the hibernate connection!

Comment: Have a look at the mysql query log. It should be executing each and every time.

Comment: it should be, but I got a connection through straight JDBC, and one through hibernate, and ran an identical query through both and then a comparison. I put a breakpoint on the comparison, it hit the breakpoint several times.

Answer (score 0):

I find the only way to be sure is to evict all the objects from he hibernate session once you have got them.

This means after you execute the statement above you need to evict each object separately, evicting the list as an object doesn't seem to work. (below assumes object names)

```
for(Balance b : listOfBalances) {
    hibernateSession.evict(b);
}
```

I doubt this is the best way to do it (I am no hibernate expert), but it is the only way I have found where you can be 100% sure that you will not receive stale objects.
(I know this reply is a bit late but hopefully it helps someone)